# what is the c# equivalent of static {...} in Java?

Tags: c#, java, static

In Java I can write:

```
public class Foo {

    public static Foo DEFAULT_FOO;

    static {
        DEFAULT_FOO = new Foo();
        // initialize 
        DEFAULT_FOO.init();
    }

    public Foo() {
    }

    void init() {
        // initialize
    }
}
```

How can I get the same functionailty in C# (where static members are initialized before use)? And, if this is a bad thing to try to do, what is a better approach?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

you use a static constructor, like this:

```
public class Foo
{
  static Foo()
  {
     // inits
  }
}
```

Here's [more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx).

Bottom line: it's a paramaterless constructor with the `static` keyword attached to it. Works just like the static block in Java.

**Edit:** One more thing to mention. If you just want to construct something statically, you can statically initialize a variable without the need for the static constructor. For example:

```
public class Foo
{
  public static Bar StaticBar = new Bar();
}
```

Keep in mind that you'll need a static constructor if you want to call any methods on Bar during static initialization, so your example that calls `Foo.Init()` still needs a static constructor. I'm just sayin' you're not limited, is all. :)

Comment: Wow! Thanks for incredibly speedy replies

Answer (score 3):

Static is still the keyword in C#:

```
public class Foo {
    public static Foo DefaultFoo;

    static Foo {
        DefaultFoo = new Foo();
        // initialize 
        DefaultFoo.init();
    }

    public Foo() {
    }

    void init() {
        // initialize
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile in C#. You need the `()` in the line `static Foo() {...}`.